# css transition effect onload other than hover suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I have been playing around with css transition effects. All is working but trying different properties other than `:hover`.

I am looking for something that transition the div onload, for instance so if I am on the page and I am scrolling down and as soon as I reach the certain div then the transition property applies.

Here is snippet I have been playing around with to get the transition started when hovering over the element, looking for something similar but that loads automatically without hovering:

```
.box {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 760px;
    height: 760px;
    background-image: url("1.png");
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

.box:hover {
    background-image: url("1.png");
    width: 760px;
    height: 760px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: you could use js !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a little Javascript to append a certain class with the appropriate transition properties to your `.box` container to apply transition on load.

Note that a `setTimeout` needs to be applied to append the class so that the transition is visible, otherwise the properties just override.

Refer the following demo:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].classList.add("transitionBox");
}, 100);
```

```css
.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: block;
  width: 760px;
  height: 760px;
  background-image: url("1.png");
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.transitionBox {
  background-image: url("1.png");
  width: 760px;
  height: 760px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Was hoping to get it done without using JavaScript. I had event in mind, as soon as the user scroll down the page and reach the certain point where the image transition is then it will apply and complete as the user scrolls down.

Comment: Without JS, the event properties applicable for css  are `hover` for block level elements, `active` & `focus` for `input/textarea` and `visited` for links. For every other kind of interaction, you will need to use Javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can make annimation css , automaticly by adding a class to that div , so whether it's `:hover` or have a class `annimation` it'll trigger : (use setTimeout to define time to start end animmation )

bellow a working snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".box").addClass("annimation");
  }, 500)
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("annimation");
  }, 3000)
})
```

```css
.box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: block;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  background-image: url("http://www.wallpaperstop.com/wallpapers/flower-wallpapers/flower-imag-336x210-0111.jpg");
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.box.annimation,
.box:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">

</div>
```